# Spring Transactional with AS400 Datasource: Rollback only works if datasource bean explicitly specifies autocommit = false

Tags: java, spring, transactions, db2

I have an issue that has been bugging me the last few days and I can't seem to figure it out. I've looked at a load of questions about it but can't seem to find one that fits my issue.

**The Scenario**

I have a service bean that has a method annotated with `@Transactional(rollbackFor=DaoException.class)`

This method calls a DAO, which calls a JdbcTemplate that interacts with a DB2 AS400 database. My configuration xml looks something like this:

```
<tx:annotation-driven proxy-target-class="true" transactionManager="txManager" />

<bean id="txManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.ibm.as400.access.AS400JDBCConnectionPoolDataSource">
    <property name=... value=... />
        ...
        ...
</bean>

<!-- Uses constructor injection to get dao -->
<bean id="service" class="com.my.package.service.MyService" />

<!-- Same, but for the JdbcTemplate -->
<bean id="dao" class="com.my.package.dao.MyDao" />

<bean id="template" class="org.springframework.blah.blah.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

OK, so this all appears to work when you look at the logs. The TransactionManager registers, it opens a transaction when the method is called, **sets the JDBC connection to manual commit**, and then claims to invoke a rollback on the database when an exception is thrown.

**BUT!** This is not actually the case.

The DAO issues a `DELETE` on my DB table, deleting two rows. It's then supposed to issue an `INSERT` to add two new rows. I've changed the code to throw the required exception after the delete. This seems to provoke the `txManager` but the effect isn't there...The rows remain missing from the DB.

If, however, I add `<property name="autoCommit" value="false" />` to the `dataSource` bean, then the same process will actually work. The data remains in the database. This makes me uncertain I'm doing the right thing. I'm pretty sure there is older code that could be affected by auto commit being switched off ...

The only thing I can add to this is that at the time of writing this, I'm not sure if the exception in the `@Transaction` annotation is an unchecked exception. I've read that checked exceptions will not cause rollbacks. But if that's the case, why do the logs appear to the contrary. I did debug through the DataSourceTransaction manager code and it was calling its rollback method too.

**My Question:**

What could cause spring to look like it's doing a rollback, as per the logs, but not actually execute it. And, why when autoCommit is set to false, does the rollback take place.

**EDIT:** I will update on the checked-vs-unchecked exception theory

Comment: The definition of AutoCommit is that the DB performs a commit after every DML operation.  That seems to be the behavior you're seeing.  The delete commits.  The rollback rolls back nothing because nothing has happened since the last commit. What is the question?

Comment: My understanding of Transactional is that the transaction is not committed until the annotated service method finishes, or a rollback occurs due to an exception. The DELETE and exception thrown are both encapsulated by a DAO method which is invoked by this service method. Also, the txManager claims to set autoCommit to false during its logging.

So why would the DELETE commit before hand?